# Angular 6 - Display of form components based on section of radiobutton

Tags: angular-material, angular6

**Scenario:**

- I am working on a form using the angular material and angular 6
- I would want to display the relevant text boxes as per the type choosen from the radio buttons which give them.

Code i have used for radio button

```
<div class="form-group m-form__group row">
    <div class="m-radio-list">
        <mat-radio-group>
            <p>
                <mat-radio-button value="newBusiness">New</mat-radio-button>
                <mat-radio-button value="renewal">Renewal</mat-radio-button>
                <mat-radio-button value="rollover">Old</mat-radio-button>
            </p>
        </mat-radio-group>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Todo :**

- So based on these 3 types, once a user selects a specific type for eg the new i want to display to him text boxes for name and number ,
   if another value then other text boxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Demo with Bydefault a checkbox selected](https://angular-27et6e.stackblitz.io)

**Application Code :** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-27et6e?file=src/app/app.component.ts

(in this code, i have selected the 3rd checkbox bydefault, you can select the first if you want)

**Approach :**

- Make 2 div container, one for `radio-buttons`, other for showing the corresponding inputs container according to selected `radio-button`.
- You can use **`change`** event like `(change)="changeComboo($event)"`, 
  i have just  used the **`ngModel`** to bind value to a variable like `[(ngModel)]="favoriteSeason"`.

**Update 1 (select bydefault first checkbox) :**

- As `mat-radio-group` is binded using `[(ngModel)]="favoriteSeason"`,
   So in function `ngOnint()`- we can assign this `favoriteSeason` variable a default value through `this.favoriteSeason = this.seasons[0];` ***(if we want to select the first checkbox)***.

Comment: thanks, also another assistance, if i would want to keep the first selection always open, how could i manage that.

Comment: thanks, also another assistance, if i would want to keep the first selection open as default for everytime one loads the app, how could i manage that.

Comment: @anglrlearner please see the updated links in the answer, and if its helpful please upvote the answer. Suggest any changes if any.

Comment: thanks, i suppose u have mistakenly added another demo code with the logic of Fetch Data from random Api, and change paginator count, could ypu please check.

Comment: @anglrlearner i am so sorry, i put the wrong link. Please see the updated link.

Comment: Thanks In my angular6 application i have a page with 6-7 accordions, and in every accordion i have form fields to be filled in and then a button to click on and submit.
I would want to open to other accordions only when the first accordion fields are filled and the button is clicked on, ie the following accordions open only if their immediate previous accordion is submitted and so on. 
How could i accomplish this 
The form field validation is different and this is different so how could i do this?

Comment: The answer is for this question asked. What you are asking is whole new question, and have to make a whole new demo for the same. Please ask a new one. As the answer is good for the asked question. Thank you. And will appreciate an upvote if my answer is helpful. Upvote is helpful for new users looking for good answers.

Comment: thanks, have added this as a new question under this link 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53552524/angular6-accordion-navigation-ie-once-completed-on-filling-all-the-form-fields', and yes i would sure want to upvote to your answer since it was a lot helpful, but since being new i do not know to do so, if you could please let me know on how i could do that, would be a lot helpful, thanks

Comment: You can accept the answer as you are new to SO, and have less reputation. See this : https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4421/can-new-users-upvote-answers-to-their-questions
So, if answer is good, please accept as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Try like this

```
<div class="radio">  
   <label>  
       <input type="radio" name="radio" value="New" (click)="setradio('New')" [checked]='true' ngModel>  
      New
  </label>  
</div>  
<div class="radio">  
 <label>  
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="Renewal" (click)="setradio('Renewal')" ngModel>  
        Renewal
  </label>  
</div>  

<div *ngIf="isSelected('New')" >  
    <input type="text"/>   New radio button selected  
</div>  

<div *ngIf="isSelected('Renewal')">  
    <input type="text"/> Renewal radio button selected  
</div>
```

> in your component.ts

```
private selectedLink: string="New";        

setradio(e: string): void {
    this.selectedLink = e;  
}  

isSelected(name: string): boolean {  

    if (!this.selectedLink) { // if no radio button is selected, always return false so every nothing is shown  
        return false;  
    }    

    return (this.selectedLink === name); // if current radio button is selected, return true, else return false  
}
```