# Angular6 Accordion Permissions, ie once completed on filling all the form fields then open to next accordion

Tags: angular, validation, accordion

In my angular6 application i have a menu page with 6-7 accordions, and in every accordion i have form fields to be filled in and then a button to submit after which it opens to the next accordion. Here i do not want to give permission to the next accordion if the previous button hasnt been clicked.
I have attached an image below, where once one clicks on the submit button, the next accordion should be made open if not should not be permitted to open it manually while clicked on the toggle
[accordion permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41eOa.png)

Comment: Can you please create a stackblitz or plunker with your code to have a look.

Comment: sure will add and post soon

Comment: https://ybmxgyjkrpk.angular.stackblitz.io/  This is the code, so here in the first accordion there is a button called submit, so one should get to open the other accordions only when the submit is clicked in the previous accordion